# Prevent Override SQLite3 Database When Deploying to AWS

Tags: django, sqlite

I'm super new to Django and currently working on an application that makes use of the awesome SQLite3 database. Only problem is that every time I deploy to AWS, the database information gets completely wiped. This is horrible for my blog because everyone's comments, likes, etc get deleted. :( How can I maintain the data after deployments? Or what can I use instead of SQLite3 without rewriting too much code?

Thanks!

Comment: Explain how you are deploying to AWS.

Comment: @DarkFalcon eb deploy [application name] from my terminal

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a file called `.ebignore`. this file works like a `.gitignore` file and you need to write filenames you didn't want to deploy by per line.

[EB CLI Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore)

Comment: after adding sqlite3 file to .ebignore its not able to find the db; throws : `no such table: django_session`